I found a series that solves my problem, but I don't understand why it works.
For a computer program I'm developing in 8-bit assembly, I needed to find a simple algorithm that increments a counter $a$ from 0 to $y$ in $x$ steps (with $x \geq y$).
By intuition, I found the following series:
$u_n = (u_{n-1} \bmod x) + y$
with $u_0 = 0$.
Each time $u_n \geq x$, I increment the counter $a$ by 1.
I run this series up to $n = x$, and I get exactly what I wanted:

$a$ is incremented regularly as the iteration progresses.
At the end, $a = y$.
And strangely, $u_x = x$.

I'm happy but I don't understand why it works. I'm not a mathematician. Can someone explain why this series works?
Thank you

Your algorithm computes something that can be expressed more simply in another form. Let $a_n$ be the value of the counter at time $n$. Then in fact your algorithm computes
$$
a_n = \biggl\lfloor \frac{ny}x \biggr\rfloor \quad(n\ge0)
$$
(where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the greatest integer not exceeding $x$). The fact that $a_x = y$ follows immediately from this formula.
In addition, $u_n$ is a variant of $ny\mod x$: we do have $u_n-ny$ being a multiple of $x$, but the values of $u_n$ are constrained to lie in $[y,x+y-1]$ rather than $[0,x-1]$. So we can say that
$$
u_n = \bigl( (n-1)y\mod x\bigr) + y \quad(n\ge1).
$$
It's also possible to show that this formula implies $u_x=x$.
